# How do display gallery embedded to the custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, gallery

I have a custom post 'events'. For each post there is a gallery attached. On a main galley page i am displaying featured images from each post . Now i want that when person clicks on this featured image , he should be taken to a new template where images from the embedded gallery of the post are displayed using get_post_gallery(). I can't use permalink because it will take me to the 'single-event'.

How can i do it ? Please help me out.

Comment: You need to give more details. How is the gallery attached? What is `get_post_gallery()`? ......

Comment: I attached the gallery using <add media> at the top of main content area . Then i created the the gallery.                         get_post_gallery is the method of getting the gallery of the current post i am using in single-events.php to get and display the gallery. Using get_post_gallery is not necessary if there is some another way.

Comment: I didn't know about [`get_post_gallery()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery), sorry, now I know what it is. So, the gallery is not attached, it is embeded. And what you need is a separate template to display the gallery embeded in the post? Am I right?

Comment: of course you are right . that is exactly what ii want to do

Comment: Any ideas how to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one good possibility is to add a endpoint to permalink for galleries and then check the template to include in the `template_include` filter:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'gallery', EP_PERMALINK );
});
add_filter( 'template_include', function($template) {
    if ( get_query_var( 'gallery' ) ) {
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-event-gallery.php';
    }
    return $template;
});
```

Now, create the file `single-event-gallery.php` and put it in your theme folder. You can copy the content of `single-event.php` and replace `the_content()` with:

```
if ( get_post_gallery() ) {
     echo get_post_gallery();
} else {
     echo "No gallery found";
}
```

You must use URLs like `mysite.com/event/a-event-post/gallery/1` ("1" is a random value, any value after "gallery/1" is valid).

I tink it is a simple, fast and easy solution but with these problems:

- It adds the endpoint rewrite rules to all permalinks
- It needs some value after `gallery` in the URL

To avoid that problems we can define a custom rewrite rule only for "event" post type and define a custom query var to use in the `template_include` fiter.

```
add_action( 'init', 'cyb_event_gallery_rewrite_rule' );
function cyb_event_gallery_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^event/([^/]+)/gallery/?$', 'index.php?event=$matches[1]&gallery=yes', 'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'cyb_register_gallery_query_var' );
function cyb_register_gallery_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'gallery';
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', function($template) {
    if ( get_query_var( 'gallery' ) ) {
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-event-gallery.php';
    }
    return $template;
});
```

Now you can use URL like `mysite.com/event/a-event-post/gallery/`. You can generate the URL inside the loop of parent post with (or similar, depends on your permalink settings):

```
$gallery_url = get_permalink() . 'gallery/';
```

Note: after you apply this code you need to flush the rewrite rules of your site. You can do that visiting the permalinks settings page and clicking in "save".

Comment: THANKS A LOT FOR HELPING ME OUT. BUT TH THING IS ITS GOING OVER MY HEAD.                                                             I copied all of the above code in functions.php                                                             What href="" do i need to give to the featured images on the gallery page

Comment: If you use the first way, you must use URL like `mysite.com/event/a-event-post/gallery/1` (with some value after "gallery"). If you use the second way you can use `mysite.com/event/a-event-post/gallery/` (without any value after "gallery"). And don't forget to flush the rewrite rules of your site.

Comment: I am using the second method.Now do i need to just add  mysite.com/event/a-event-post/gallery/ to the href of feature images on gallery or page .

Comment: Yes, that is. And remember to create the single-event-gallery.php template file. If my answer fix your problem and help you, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: i used href="http://localhost/basswaves/a-event-post/gallery/"   but it gives me error object not found.       i created the single-events-gallery.php . 'events ' is the custom post

Comment: I tested the code I posted before to post it and it works. Have you flushed the rewrite rules? Also, if you are using the "event" custom post type, the expected URL is `localhost/basswaves/event/a-event-post/gallery/` and it is the one expected by the code I posted. Have you set aditional rewrite rules to make the custom post type URL without the "event" slug?

Comment: In the question you said that you are using "event" post type. Is it "event" or "events"? Anyway, if you use [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function, the correct URL for the event will be generated and you only have to add the "gallery" endpoint.

Comment: sorry was in remote area with no internet connectivity. i mistyped event but its events. i replaced it with events in all the code.                                                        i used href="localhost/basswaves/events/a-events-post/gallery/" for the featured images on the main gallery page or do i have to use i use get_permalink() . 'gallery/'  as explained above by you.                                           I am only using the rewrite rules given in your code and no other rules.

Comment: get_permalink is giving me http://localhost/basswaves/?events=music-concert/ and not localhost/basswaves/events/a-events-post/gallery/

Comment: and if i use href="get_permalink().'/gallery/'". i get to the  index.php with url http://localhost/basswaves/?events=rave/gallery/

Comment: It seems like you don't have pretty URLs activated, so you have to use the gallery endpoint as query var: `localhost/basswaves/?events=rave&gallery=yes` instead of ` localhost/basswaves/?events=rave/gallery`. In general `get_permalink().'&gallery=yes'` instead of `get_permalink().'/gallery/'`.

Comment: how can i make it work for the permalinks other than default permalink

Comment: please man just help me out with this , 
how can i make it work for the permalinks other than default permalink